# How can I save values from recursive functions in c?

Tags: c, function, recursion, store

I wrote a program which displays the points between points which the user types in.

For example: User types points `A(1|1)` and `B(10|10)`, so the program returns all the points which make a line between `A` and `B` (therefore `(2|2) (3|3)(4|4)(5|5)(6|6)` etc..(imagine a 2 dimensional array).
For calculating the points in between I've used a recursive function which looks like this:

```
void line(struct point A, struct point B) {
    struct point M;
    if ((A.x - B.x >= -1 && A.x - B.x <= 1) && (A.y - B.y >= -1 && A.y - B.y <= 1)) {
        printf("P(%i|%i) P(%i|%i)\n", A.x, A.y, B.x, B.y);

    }
    else {
        M.x = (A.x + B.x) / 2;
        M.y = (A.y + B.y) / 2;
        line(A, M);
        line(M, B);

    }
}
```

Now I have to visualize this, means create a 2 dimensional array whcih shows point A and B and the points in between can be every character(* or 0 for example). How do I do that, since I dont know how to save the values of the recursive function? I tried a lot of thinking, but did not find a solution.

Comment: I personally would just preserve the list of points calculated . i.e `M` in a 1-d array and then just read it. Arrays are pas by reference anyway. So regardless if you choose 1-d or 2-3 array just send that as an argument to the function and keep pushing the new value of m to that array. The downside of a 2d array is you don't know where to go next when reading the array.

Comment: Perhaps you could pass a pointer to allocated memory through the recursion (with its number of elements), reallocate when full, add the next interpolated point to the end, and return the number of elements. Finally sort the array before printing. It might be easier to get that working with global variables first, before converting to function arguments and return values.

Comment: Typically you would try to use a solution which needs no "state" except for the stack built implicitly by the recursive calls. In particular one should avoid static "state" variables the way Abhijit does with `i` and `j`. It would be better to pass just a pointer that the function writes to as a parameter (or pass indices). The pointer is / the indexes are computed for each recursive call in the calling code. Think about recursively printing a binary tree. You just get a root node and you don't care or want to know how deep down you are. The stack keeps track of that.

Comment: what happens when the second point coordinate is below the first point coordinate?  What happens when the second point coordinate is to the left of the first point coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a static two dimensional array inside your recursive function. And finally return that array.

This is just an example but not the final solution. Hence you have to apply this example in your codes:-

```
int** line(struct point A, struct point B)
{
   static int** array2D =(int **)malloc(somesize * sizeof(int *));

   static int i=0;
   static int j=0;

   .
   .
   M.x = (A.x + B.x) / 2;
   M.y = (A.y + B.y) / 2;

   array2D[i][j++] =  M.x;
   array2D[i++][j] =  M.y;
   .
   .

 return array2D;
```

Comment: I like that you leak your previous allocation of `array2D` on every new call to `line()`. I also like that you call it "2D" when it's clearly 1D.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I assume you suppose that since it's `static` that it's being initialized only once on the first encounter. While that's true, the point where it's assigned a non-`0` pointer (where space is allocated) is not at that point in time; it's on every call to `line()`.

Comment: What is `new` ?

Comment: @WeatherVane Good point. Based on your mega-rep, I'm guessing you know this but for others: That's C++'s version of `malloc()`. And this is a C question.

Comment: @phonetagger Yeah, the alloc is called every time, true, and the code has changed now anyway...

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider The code has changed, but not for the better. It's still leaking on every call, and it can't possibly be maintaining a full record of all traversals since the record of the previous call is lost on each subsequent call. The final returned `array2D` has only a single valid entry (the last one), and what's returned is mostly uninitialized garbage (or perhaps a bunch of zeros if it happens to be memory that was allocated for the very first time since the program started).

Comment: So do we think that the code were better if the array was initialized in the declaration, i.e. the malloc would be executed just once, as I initially thought?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, Thanks for your advice. I changed the codes. :-)

Comment: Another thing is that you could directly allocate a static array like `static int array2D[SIZE_X][SIZE_Y];` or the like, assuming two defines for the number of points in each direction. You could also have it as a global variable in your program. (But as I said elsewhere its's not necessarily a good pattern for a recursive function to operate on static data).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a pointer to a structure and store the points into an array in that structure:

```
struct curve {
    size_t pos, size;
    struct point *points;
};

void line(struct curve *cp, struct point A, struct point B) {
    if ((A.x - B.x >= -1 && A.x - B.x <= 1)
    &&  (A.y - B.y >= -1 && A.y - B.y <= 1)) {
        if (cp->pos >= cp->size) {
            int new_size = (cp->size + cp->size / 2 + 6);
            struct point *np = realloc(cp->points, sizeof(*np) * new_size);
            if (np == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            cp->points = np;
            cp->size = new_size;
        }
        if (cp->pos == 0) {
            cp->points[cp->pos++] = A;
        }
        cp->points[cp->pos++] = B;
    } else {
        struct point M;
        M.x = (A.x + B.x) / 2;
        M.y = (A.y + B.y) / 2;
        line(cp, A, M);
        line(cp, M, B);
    }
}
```

Initial call:

```
    struct curve c = { 0, 0, NULL };
    line(&c, A, B);
```